# drawing a line from gesture between 2 buttons

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I am beginner for interactions on iphone. I have 3 buttons, one on the left, and the 2 other ones on the right. I would like to push the left button with finger and display a line real time stretching with my finger moving on screen that goes to the other button I am going to go to on the right - and then I reach the button on the right and release my finger the line stays on screen.

Where should I start in the manual to understand how to do something like this?
- please don't say page 1 ;-)

thanks for all the pointers so I can learn and write the code myself

Cheers,
geebee

Comment: Can we assume that you (besides your iPhone experience) are an advanced programmer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, uh, you're jumping right into the deep end.

First, the answer to your question is ... check out the [Sample Code at developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code).  By playing with those sample projects, and running them in the debugger, and reading that code, you can learn a whole lot about what you're trying to do.

Using those samples as your tutorial, refer to specific information in the reference docs also available at [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com). There are specific docs on the classes you'll be using (e.g. [UIButton Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)), and there are high level *guides* that talk about different areas, like the [Event Handling Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541), and [Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156).

Here are some of the issues you're going to face, and some of the areas that you should read up on:

- UIButtons are going to respond to your touch and won't allow any other view to receive that touch *without some special handling in your code*.
- Check out samples that deal with UITouch events, Quartz 2D drawing, creating custom controls
- Try doing this without any buttons first, that's fairly simple. Just figure out how to detect a TouchDownInside event, track the finger movement across the screen, and detect a TouchUpInside event, all in a normal UIView. (*There may be a sample for this.*)

Comment: I thought initially that 2 buttons would be more difficult so I will follow your advice and start with no buttons. thx